# changes to python code not having effect using colcon build --symlink-install

Tags: ros2, build, ros-humble, colcon

I am trying to make a publisher by reading the sensor values and sending it throughout.
I had an issue at first, so I changed the arguments in the main function as:

```
dist_pub.send_uart_command('0x80 0x06 0x03 0x77')
```

However, the error in the log still shows me of the old arguments I was passing:

```
dist_pub.send_uart_command(b'\x80\x06\x03\x77')
```

It seems colcon build --symlink-install is malfunctioning.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue. The version of ROS2 I'm using is Humble.

The following is my src:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
import serial
from std_msgs.msg import String

class UARTSensorNode(Node):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__('uart_sensor_node')
       self.serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
       self.get_logger().info('UART Sensor Node has been started')
       self.prox_sen_pub = self.create_publisher(String, 'sensor_data', 10)

   def send_uart_command(self, command):
       # Send the HEX command as a string
       self.serial_port.write(command)

def receive_sensor_data(self):
    data = self.serial_port.read(8)  # Read 8 bytes, adjust as needed
    sensor_data_str = data.decode('utf-8')
    msg = String()
    msg.data = sensor_data_str
    self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)
    self.prox_sen_pub.publish(msg)

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    dist_pub = UARTSensorNode()
    dist_pub.send_uart_command('0x80 0x06 0x03 0x77')  # Send the HEX command as a bytes object
    dist_pub.receive_sensor_data()
    rclpy.spin(dist_pub)
    dist_pub.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The following is the log:

```
parallels@ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop:~/agv_control$ colcon build --symlink-install
Starting >>> proximity_sense
Finished <<< proximity_sense [0.62s]          

Summary: 1 package finished [0.96s]
parallels@ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop:~/agv_control$ source ~/agv_control/install/setup.bash
parallels@ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop:~/agv_control$ ros2 run proximity_sense uart_sensor_node
[INFO] [1699423940.792314802] [uart_sensor_node]: UART Sensor Node has been started
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/parallels/agv_control/install/proximity_sense/lib/proximity_sense/uart_sensor_node", line 33, in <module>
      sys.exit(load_entry_point('proximity-sense', 'console_scripts', 'uart_sensor_node')())
    File "/home/parallels/agv_control/install/UART_on/lib/python3.10/site-packages/UART_on/proximity_sensor.py", line 28, in main
      dist_pub.send_uart_command(b'\x80\x06\x03\x77')  # Send the HEX command as a bytes object
    File "/home/parallels/agv_control/install/UART_on/lib/python3.10/site-packages/UART_on/proximity_sensor.py", line 15, in send_uart_command
      self.serial_port.write(command.encode())
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'. Did you mean: 'decode'?
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you building the right package?

I've often had the issue that especially when building only one package in isolation, code updated in other packages is not updated. Try building your workspace in its entirety, or if that is really unfeasible use the `--packages-up-to` option.

Answer (score 1):

Try first to remove the `install` and `build` folders and build again. It could be because you already installed without `symlink`.

NOTE: this will erase install/build files for all packages, if you want only for your package, get into `install` and `build` and erase them individually

```bash
rm -r /build /install
colcon build --symlink-install
```